Contents of NUnit3TestAdapter NuGet package are not copied to buid output directory of test project on .NET 8 on MacOS ARM
I am trying to build, run and debug tests of my company's C# solution on MacOS ARM using VS Code with C# Dev Kit extension. Everything works well besides the issue in the title, thus test discovery doesn't occur. If I copy the files from the package by hand into the bin/Debug folder and restart VS Code, everything works as expected. Contents of other packages, such as NUnit itself, are copied successfully. Test project in the solution uses <PackageReference> syntax and compiles to DLL file. I can't supply the whole .csproj file obviously due to legal issues.
I have tried creating sample test project by example from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/testing
That project builds correctly, copies NUnit3TestAdapter's contents and discovers and runs tests correctly without any manual action required. It also compiles to DLL file, uses the same <PackageReference> syntax, I've tried pasting section with package references from the sample project to company's test project in case that maybe entry order matters, without success - the contents of NUnit3TestAdapter are still not copied.
Current section with package references looks as follows:

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

Solutions to similar issues suggested trying adding
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

section to project file, that did not produce any effect, and as far as I could find, that option is not processed since .NET 6.
The issue is not critical, as I can do the copying manually, but the issue clearly indicates I'm missing something which could potentially cause more serious issues, so I would be thankful for help.
